# tfjs-node giving ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow

I am trying to use tfjs-node on my nodejs server but on writing the import statement I get this error
[image]

```
//my import statements
import express from "express";
import pool from "../config/pgConfig.cjs";
import path from "path";
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs-node";


//my package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@braintree/sanitize-url": "^7.0.0",
    "@mediapipe/face_detection": "^0.4.1646425229",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.39.7",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.11.2",
    "@tensorflow-models/blazeface": "^0.1.0",
    "@tensorflow-models/face-detection": "^1.0.2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.17.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "^4.17.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^4.17.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^4.17.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^4.17.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu": "^4.17.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "easy-waf": "^0.5.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.3",
    "express-rate-limit": "^7.1.5",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "helmet": "^7.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^8.0.0",
    "perfect-express-sanitizer": "^1.0.13",
    "permissions-policy": "^0.6.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "python-shell": "^5.0.0",
    "rate-limiter-flexible": "^4.0.0",
    "redis": "^4.6.13",
    "spdy": "^4.0.2",
    "tiny-csrf": "^1.1.3",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.13",
    "winston": "^3.11.0"
  }
```

I have tried the following

1. updated npm
2. deleted node_modules and then npm install
3. npm install bcrypt

still not working now how do I run tensorflow model in backend is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: move D:\TFJS\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-node\deps\lib\tensorflow.dll to D:\TFJS\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v8\